# How to set the location of new fields when user scrolls to a random location

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to create a new line of Textbox when user clicks a button. But if the user scrolls down and then clicks the button, the new Textbox will appear to be lower than I'd like them to be. How do I approach this so that the textboxes will be aligned?

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TotalNumberAdded++;

        AddControls(TotalNumberAdded);
    }

    private void AddControls(int rowCounter)
    {

        // Convert 'rowCounter' to string
        string counter = rowCounter.ToString();
        // Create new TextBox
        var newTextbox = new TextBox();
        //panel1.Controls.Add(newTextbox);
        newTextbox.Name = "txt_" + counter;
        //newTextbox.Location = new Point(60, y);            
        newTextbox.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left);
        newTextbox.Top = y;
        newTextbox.Left = 60;
        // Add items to panel, then add panel to form
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(newLabel);
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(newTextbox);
        y = y + 40;
    }
```

Comment: This is not `vb.net`, please remove this tag from question.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. Create an anchor label in the panel and use the now relative position `newTextbox.Top = mAnchor.Location.Y + y;` as the Y axis.